# Install google api php client on Cent OS in php.ini using include_path

Tags: php, server, google-api-php-client, php-ini

I am trying to install and use `google-api-php-client` in wordpress and my php applications.
I have requested my administrator manager to install it. They have included the following script to `php.ini` file. 
`include_path=".;/usr/local/src/google-api-php-client/src"` 
Now I want to include and use google api in my wordpress application. I created a file called google.php in wordpress root to test this out, In my research I have found now I need to just include this bit of code in php file and everything will be up and running.
`require 'Google/Client.php';`
`require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

At the End I get an error like this:
`Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Google/Client.php' (include_path='.;/usr/local/src/google-api-php-client/src') in`

Could you help me fix this???

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the autoload.php file. This file takes care of loading the other classes including Google/Client.php. See this link: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client